# Reload cache on change of database

Tags: .net, sql, caching, sqldependency, invalidation

I'm developing a .net client application which uses Entity Framework to access the database. It is a multiuser application where (sometimes) there are no changes for hours possibly days and sometimes there are hundreds of changes at once.

I need to cache pretty much data because of some checks which need to be done and displayed to the user. I solved the problem of one cache updating the others when something changes within one application instance. However I'm not sure what is the best way to go when the change happens in an other instance of the application.

I tried to use `SqlDependency` to invalidate my caches but that can force me to reload very much data when only one bit has changed. Not very good for performance. Also it fires when the application which uses the `SqlDependecy` changes something at the data so one change gets a cache updated twice.

Since I never developed something with that amount of caching I'm at a loss of how I'd best proceed. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why does a single bit change force you to reload very much data?

Comment: Well maybe I do something wrong but when I get the notification I don't know what exactly has been changed so I can't just reload the changed data. I need to relaod all that could have changed under the SqlCommand. For example all elements in Table 'A' where fk...=x. Can be quite some data.

Comment: Understand but a single bit still does not force you to reload all the data.  You could read read the data and only update data that is changed.  Or you could implement a trigger on SQL that writes out the changes so you only have to check that table.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. It sounds like a good solution to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single bit still does not force you to reload all the data.
You could read read the data and only update data that is changed.

Or you could implement a trigger on SQL that writes out the changes so you only have to check that table.
If multiple clients are syncing from the trigger table then could have another FK table that the client can indicate what they picked up.
And clear out stuff out like nightly.

Comment: Your answer definitly got me going. I'm just not sure whether I should use triggers or the `Change Tracking` provided by `SQL Server` (2008 R2 and newer). With the solution using triggers I've got more control but must do it for every table. Or is there a possibility to do it for all tables in one trigger? (I never used triggers before)

Comment: I am suggesting both.   Change Tracking to notify.  Then trigger to identify which data changed.   I don't think you can have one trigger for all table and doubt that is the best solution anyway.  Surely you have some tables that are not updated by users.  And you don't want the trigger tables to trigger.   You could have multiple triggers write to the same table.